# Showing this detection message => Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a few functions in my project with jest. And for that, I imported one of the functions `displayVouchers` that should returns a string, from the module `'../Buy Raffle Voucher/index'`. Now, this `displayVouchers` function does not communicate with redis in any way whatsoever, although the `'../Buy Raffle Voucher/index'` module imports a function from a module (`./selectedVoucherHandlers`) that has a redis connection. In my test file `buyRaffleVoucher.test.js` file, as soon the test finishes running, regardless of whether the test passes or fails, I always get the message `Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting`. I'm running my test with `--detectOpenHandles` flag.

## This is the full message I'm getting after the test runs

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  Timeout

      1 | const Redis = require('ioredis');
      2 |
    > 3 | const redis = new Redis();
        |               ^
      4 |
      5 | redis.on('connect', () => {
      6 |     console.log('Redis connection successful');

      at node_modules/ioredis/built/connectors/StandaloneConnector.js:44:21
      at StandaloneConnector.connect (node_modules/ioredis/built/connectors/StandaloneConnector.js:43:16)
      at node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:121:64
      at EventEmitter.connect (node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:103:25)
      at new Redis (node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:77:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/config/redis.js:3:15)
      at Object.require (app/Buy Raffle Voucher/selectedVoucherHandlers.js:2:15)
      at Object.require (app/Buy Raffle Voucher/index.js:1:36)
      at Object.require (app/tests/buyRaffleVoucher.test.js:1:29)
```

## this is my buyRaffleVoucher.test.js file

```
const { displayVouchers } = require('../Buy Raffle Voucher/index');

describe("All buy-raffle-voucher here", () => {
    it('should return available vouchers', () => {
        expect(displayVouchers()).toBe("Select a voucher amount\n1. N200\n2. N500\n3. N1000");
    }); 
});
```

## my redis connection file

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');

const redis = new Redis();

redis.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Redis connection successful');
});


// redis.on('error', () => {
//     console.log('Redis connection failed');
// })

module.exports = redis;
```

I imported the redis connection to my test file, then called `redis.disconnect()` in the `afterAll()` hook, and it worked. But then I have other functions that communicate with redis to test, and I have to mock redis in order to test these functions, but as soon as I mock redis, `redis.disconnect()` doesn't work anymore.

## my test file after I mock redis

```
const { displayVouchers } = require('../Buy Raffle Voucher/index');
const { onAmountSelected } = require('../Buy Raffle Voucher/selectedVoucherHandlers');

let redis = require('../config/redis');

afterAll(() => {
    redis.disconnect();
})

jest.mock('../config/redis');

describe("All buy-raffle-voucher here", () => {
    it('should return available vouchers', () => {
        expect(displayVouchers()).toBe("Select a voucher amount\n1. N200\n2. N500\n3. N1000");
    }); 

    it("should return recipient types", async () => {
        const result = await onAmountSelected(['0', '1'], 'dasdjl')
        redis.hset.mockResolvedValueOnce(1);
        expect(redis.hset).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toBe('CON Voucher is for \n 1 Self \n 2 Others'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I finally got it working with the snippet:

```
afterAll(async () => {
const actualRedis = jest.requireActual('../config/redis');
await actualRedis.quit();
```

});